# How do I find a paid version of Didot LT Bold if I want to use it commercially?

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-licensing

I can't find a single version of the font that has a commercial license, what do I do? Do I just settle for another font?

https://www.fontsmarket.com/font-details/didot-lt-std-bold
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/73537/didot-lt-std-bold

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase the font on Linotype.com, they are the creators of the font. They call that specific weight [LINOTYPE DIDOT™ BOLD](https://www.linotype.com/1195955/linotype-didot-bold-product.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get Theano Didot from Font Squirrel or FontSpace. The license is SIL Open Font License v1.10 - free for commercial use.

There's unfortunately only one weight. Check, can you use it.

Commercial font supplier Optimo has family Didot Elder. It has several weights Check it here https://optimo.ch/typefaces_Didot-Elder.html  Read something about it: https://typographica.org/on-typography/the-didot-you-didnt-know/